# Puppeteer/headless Chromium on Alpine font issues

Tags: google-chrome, docker, chromium, puppeteer, alpine-linux

I'm using Puppeteer in an Alpine Linux Docker container. The container inherits from `node:alpine`.

By default, it renders English fine, however it doesn't render Japanese at all.

I had a look at [Puppeteer's Docker docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/717d4a7ada6f82a8dce8f801a7136d15c3b17df1/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker), which are tailored to Debian; we are using Alpine.

To render Japanese I ran `apk add font-ipa@edge`, which installed an appropriate font.

However, now Chromium uses *that* font to render English, and it looks bad. I've tried installing other fonts on top, eg `apk add ttf-freefont@edge`, but that doesn't change anything. It still uses the Japanese font.

How can I make Chromium use a specific Japenese font to render Japanese text, but a different (the default) font to render non-Japanese text? What fonts need installing?

We can't use another distro; it must be Alpine.

Comment: Relevant question https://superuser.com/questions/192704/why-cant-my-chromium-display-japanese-characters

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer provided by browserless above worked for me, however the code file that was linked has changed. I had to dig through the file history to find what he was talking about.  So for anyone searching for this in the future. Here is the code I think was being referred to.  It solved my issues.

Add these things to your docker file.

```
ENV font_directory /usr/share/fonts/noto

# Install fonts
RUN mkdir -p $font_directory
RUN cd $font_directory &&\
    wget https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-cjk/blob/master/NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf?raw=true && \
    fc-cache -f -v
```

Other Noto font libraries can be found here https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-hans

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a docker image [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/browserless/chrome/) that achieves what you're looking for (using system fonts but then other's when needed). More specifically the font browserless uses is Google's own Noto CJK font ([this line](https://github.com/joelgriffith/browserless/blob/master/Dockerfile#L82) in the Dockerfile).

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to install Noto CJK with Alpine but it's the only variant that there isn't a repository for; the wget line is useful